# How to add Chart image to HtmlTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am generating a chart completely dynamically in codebehind file and saving image to jpeg format.

```
Chart Chart1 = new Chart();

Chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
Chart1.DataBind();
Chart1.Series.Add(new Series());
Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Pie;
Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "bloodType";
Chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Total";

Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
Chart1.ImageType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImageType.Jpeg;


Chart1.SaveImage("C:\\MyChartImage.jpg", ChartImageFormat.Jpeg);


HtmlTable tbProductImage = new HtmlTable();
HtmlTableRow trImageRow = new HtmlTableRow();



HtmlTableCell tdImageCell = new HtmlTableCell();

//Get generaqted image.
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imageVar = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
imageVar .Visible = true;
imageVar .ImageUrl = "C:\\MyChartImage.jpg";


tdImageCell.Controls.Add(imageVar );
trImageRow.Cells.Add(tdImageCell);

tbProductImage.Rows.Add(trImageRow);
this.Controls.Add(tbProductImage);
```

the chart image gets generated succesfully in C:\ drive but when I try to put it in HTMl table cell , nothing is rendered . No error is shown . How to display image ? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save to Image folder in your web application, if you don't have image folder, create it

```
Chart1.SaveImage(Server.MapPath("~/Image/MyChartImage.jpg"));
```

then

```
imageVar.ImageUrl = "~/Image/MyChartImage.jpg";
```

image URL like `C:\folder1\....` will not work, you need to give `Absolute URL` like `http://localhost:3458/Image/MyChartImage.jpg` or Relative URL like `~/Image/MyChartImage.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Damith's answer, paths on a website are relative to the root of your website. This is what is referred to when you see the tilda ~

`Server.MapPath("~/")` will always get you the root folder of the website you are currently in from codebehind. From there you need to create your folders and save your files. Then if you save your files in a folder called images, you can refer to your saved file via the relative syntax "/images/filename.ext" while in html. Why? Because "/" points to the root of your site in html.

You can also use the [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) object to create you relative paths of your files as long as keep them inside your website root somewhere. See [MakeRelativeUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.makerelativeuri.aspx)